# Debug remote .NET Core console app in Linux Docker fails with Visual Studio

Tags: linux, docker, visual-studio, debugging, .net-core

I'm trying to debug a .NET Core 6 console app running in an Ubuntu LTS docker container on a Debian 10 Linux server from my Windows 11 Visual Studio IDE CE Preview.

Following [these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-dotnet-core-linux-with-ssh?view=vs-2022) instructions:

- I attach using SSH and Keys.
- I see the containers.
- I attach to the container.
- I see my process.
- I attach to the process.
- I select Managed .NET Core for Linux.
- I get this error:

```
Failed to launch debug adapter 'coreclr'.
Unable to find debugger script at '/nonexistent/.vs-debugger'.


Initialization log:
Determining user folder on remote system...
Checking for existing installation of debugging tools...
Downloading debugger launcher...
Creating debugger installation folder: /nonexistent/.vs-debugger
Failed: "Command 'mkdir -p '/nonexistent/.vs-debugger'' failed with code '1'. "
Unable to find debugger script at '/nonexistent/.vs-debugger'.
Failed: Unable to find debugger script at '/nonexistent/.vs-debugger'.
The program '[1] PlexCleaner' has exited with code 4294967295 (0xffffffff).
```

Similar error when remote attach in VSCode, and then attach to container:

```
[2354 ms] Start: Installing VS Code Server
[2354 ms] Start: Run in container: mkdir -p /nonexistent/.vscode-server-insiders/bin/0b3574dcef8f35fec4ee4f83dc958c1f16ef6fce-insider_1656694640395
[2360 ms] 
[2361 ms] mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/nonexistent’: Permission denied
[2361 ms] Exit code 1
[2364 ms] Command in container failed: mkdir -p /nonexistent/.vscode-server-insiders/bin/0b3574dcef8f35fec4ee4f83dc958c1f16ef6fce-insider_1656694640395
[2364 ms] mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/nonexistent’: Permission denied
[2364 ms] Exit code 1
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

There may be more elegant solutions, but I found that by manually installing the  debugging tools I can attach without issue.

E.g. I now conditionally install the SDK and debug tools vs. just the runtime:

```
ARG DBGTOOL_INSTALL=""
RUN wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/$(lsb_release -sr)/packages-microsoft-prod.deb \
    && dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb \
    && apt-get update \
    && if [ -n "$DBGTOOL_INSTALL" ] ; then \
         apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-6.0 ; \
       else \
         apt-get install -y dotnet-runtime-6.0 ; \
       fi \
    && rm packages-microsoft-prod.deb \
    && dotnet --info

# Install remote debug tools
RUN if [ -n "$DBGTOOL_INSTALL" ] ; then \
      wget https://aka.ms/getvsdbgsh \
      && sh getvsdbgsh -v latest -l /vsdbg \
      && rm getvsdbgsh ; \
    fi
```